# Applying the Leray-Hirsch theorem on certain manifolds

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles

Let $M$ be a connected closed orientable manifold with Euler characteristic $0$. Let $TM$ be the tangent bundle over $M$ and $SM$ be the induced sphere bundle with fiber $S^{n-1}$.

Looking at page 432 of Hatcher's book "Algebraic Topology", I'm trying to see if the fiber bundle $SM$ satisfies all the requirements of the Leray-Hirsch theorem, with coefficient ring $\mathbb{Z}$.

I can verify that condition $(a)$ is satisfied, the cohomology groups of the sphere are always finitely generated for every dimension. I'm stumped for condition $(b)$. To be honest I'm not sure I understand its statement at all.

Could I get an explanation about what that condition is saying, so that I can attempt to verify for $SM$?

Comment: In your case, it's asking for a cohomology class $c \in H^{n-1}(SM; \mathbb{Z})$ such that its restriction to each fiber is a generator of $H^{n-1}(S^{n-1}; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: I see, and so since the fiber bundle is orientable, we will get that each choice of generator will be the same? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: If you have such a $c$, then you will get an orientation for the sphere bundle, but the existence of an orientation for the sphere bundle does not imply the existence of the desired class $c$.